# Processing file path from uploaded file on client side

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get a small text file uploaded to the client without reading the file and converting it into a string or a dataurl. Just returning the temporary path of the file in browser cache to a javascript function? No storage of the file on server side, just on the client.

Comment: Well you seem to have your answer in the title already. (if you're going to a self-answer, there are already dupes)

Comment: @Kaiido actually I was reading documentation of the api and filereader converts files into strings or dataurls; unless I read wrong of course.

Comment: I think you are looking for "blob object"

Comment: Ah maybe I read your question wrong. You **don't** want to read it nor to convert to a string or dataURI ? Then it's quite unclear what you want. You can just store the File object in a variable (which is a Blob), but it will die with the page. If you want to store it like in localStorage, then you'll have to read it and convert it to a string, only strings can be saved to localStorage. Also, you can't get the absolute path of a file from user input, and anyway, you couldn't access it afterwards.

Comment: @Kaiido If it dies with the page that is ok, but what I am aiming for is if I upload a tsv file and I have a function that **has** been taking a argument filepath (which I hardcoded locally) to the filepath of an uploaded file, I can run my script without storing the file in a database. I hope that added clarity.

Comment: Ah I think I got it : You've got a function that has been written to receive a filepath (on server), but you want to use it against user uploaded files, right? Then what you need is the `URL` Object and its [`createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method. This will create a temporary path to browser's memory, where the file will be accessible. Note that it will also die with the page.